# Setting a label to display the the outcome of a method on initialization c#

Tags: c#

so i have a very simple application (beginner learning the basics here "/) which is shown below, and was just wondering how to get the label (the output of method "checkDiscount") to display the first instance when the form initially loads. As i have for now just set the text property of the label to what the two checked radio buttons would produce, which obviously is pretty poor programming. Again sorry if this is a god awful noob question....

```
private void checkDiscount()
    {
        int discount;

        if (radOAP.Checked == true)
        {
            if (radFully.Checked == true)
                discount = 40;
            else
                discount = 25;
        }
        else if (radStudent.Checked == true)
        {
            if (radFully.Checked == true)
                discount = 35;
            else
                discount = 20;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (radFully.Checked == true)
                discount = 5;
            else
            {
                if (chkPlym.Checked == true)
                    discount = 15;
                else
                    discount = 0;
            }
        }

        lblDiscount.Text = "Your Discount is " + Convert.ToString(discount) + "%";
    }
```

---

So what i want is to display the outcome discount of OAP & Fully when the form initially laods (which just means they receive 40% discount) without having to set the text property manually myself.

Thanks if anyone can shed some light on this annoying hindrance :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without having to set the text property manually myself"?

Comment: so when the form loads the labels text property is set to default text property of label 1 or whatever you set it too. but i would like to have the label set to the result of having the two radio buttons checked. I should imagine i can move a portion of the code to make this happen but am not sure what bit an where. its just so when the user first loads the program the label isnt displaying some default rubbish as it looks bad and is ultimately bad programming right? although right now i will happily admit im really not great aha

Answer (score 0):

Create:

```
private  int discount = 40;
```

in your

```
public partial class Form1 class
```

and then in your Form constructor set:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.lblDiscount.Text = discount.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad idea.  You don't want to modify code in the designer files as they're generated and your code isn't guaranteed to not disappear.

Comment: Also, there's no reason for the `discount` member variable to be public.

Comment: That's fine.  :)  Also, as a note to OP, you can't access form items (labels, textboxes, etc.) before the call to `InitializeComponent`.  A better option would probably be to put this code in the form's `Load()` event.  Ultimately, though, after reading the question again, I don't think this answers the OP's question at all.

Comment: That does answer (i didn't word the question too well) but yea that was what i wanted to know, thanks for the clarification Tim that was really bugging me and obviously i am in need of some serious practice "/